# Multiple queries

Tags: c#, .net, database, ado.net

I've got a ADO.NET question, Indeed, I'd like to know if it's possible to do *blind query execution*; which means the user enters anything in a text box (well it's supposed to be SQL or T-SQL statement(s)), then when he submits I want to execute its input on the fly, I've seen that ADO.NET has different methods for SELECT and INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE statements, so to conclude, is there a way to just execute a bunch of statements without checking their kind first ? (the query could contain ";" separated queries so...)

Thanks in advance,

Miloud Bel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database supports multiple statements you could separate them with `;` and execute in one go: `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Of course fetching the results could be messy if you mix SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE in the same query. You may also [check this sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/ExecutemultipleSQLstatementsusingaSqlCommandobject.htm).

Comment: Will fetching the results return the last query output only ? (if so, that would be great). And what about stored procedures ? Can I mix calls to them in my block ? Thanks :)

Comment: If you use `ExecuteReader` you can fetch the results from all SELECTs.

Comment: Actually I only want to get the last query output, this behavior is perfect for my app. Thank you Darin :)